24.04 - How to fix E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file
Hello and thanks in advance for your help.
Upon running the command sudo apt update I get the following error message:-

E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

The contents of that file are as follows:-
Types: deb
URIs: cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230807.2)]/
Suites: jammy
Components: main restricted

I am unable to spot the error.
Can you recommend a fix?
As always, thanks in advance,
Cameron.

Why would you be trying to resolve that file; the initial jammy or 22.04.3 media will contain nothing of value for your system that has been release-upgraded. I'll suggest just removing or disabling that entry completely.
